# Types of Neural Networks to compare for stock prediction

Tags: matlab, neural-network

i am currently doing a project on stock price predictions using neural networks. I intend to compare 3 different neural networks using the same data inputs (historical data and some technical indicators) and then predict the next day closing stock price using the different NNs.

I know the multi-layer perceptron (MLP) is probably the most basic so what 2 other artificial neural networks should I compare it to and why? Any help to point me in the correct direction will be appreciated. thanks!

I am using MATLAB for this project so if any available source codes for a start where I can look at the code and try to understand what is happening will be good

Comment: I found this machine learning class on coursera, https://www.coursera.org/course/ml, to be very helpful.  Refer to the programming assignment for weeks 4 & 5 for matlab code that fully implements a neural network.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Focus disambiguition:**

**Focus on ANN-types:**

If your demo-Project intent is focused on just demonstrating a different "**technology**" used inside an ANN-based predictor(s), there are feasible academic sources for finding 3 different types -- { perceptrons, RBM, auto-encoders, recurrent-NNs, deeply-recurrent } -- to be tested as you wish to get raw results to be published. Be warned, that your computational resources for some of the types need not be available so straightforward. So choose with a care according to your time, level-of-detail you plan to address and budget.

**Focus on a Quality of ANN-Training process**:

If your Project aims at comparison of respective progress that various ANN have during the process of the ANN-Training ( convergence, sensitivity to bias / overfitting, an ability / a degree of generalisation ), there is no need to spend a lot of efforts on ANN-Design, but you will need adequate amount of `data[M,N]` a good optimiser-based framework to fine-tune your experimental ANN's parametrisation. Remember your computational complexity of the problem ... O( f(N) ) ... your fight will be on the optimiser parametrisation state-space vs. O( f(N) ) on your actual scale of the data[m,n+s]

**Focus on a Quality of Predictions** produced in a Forward-testing ( on Out-of-sample data ):

If your Project aims at achieving some more complex quantitative comparison of the Predictors' output, there are more important aspects, than just a **type**-of-Neural-Network.

1. ANN-OutputLAYER Design **`Out[j]`** ( What exactly shall be the intended Predictor's output? )
2. Input data`[M,N]` cleansing`[m<M,N]` & sanity
3. Missing & erroneous data-elements handling
4. Features`[n<N]` selection & synthetic Features`[s]` construction ... i.e.
   **Feature-Engineering**
5. ANN-InputLAYER Design **`In[n+s]`**
6. ANN-Architecture Design { `In[n+s]`, **`Hidden[xthLAYER][varNODEs]`**, `Out[j]` }
7. ANN-Architecture Connectivity Model